# Looping through a nested array, testing and outputing results with the same structure

Tags: php, arrays

Hi I wonder if anyone can point me in the right direction with this problem, I just don't know where to start.

I have an array that follows this structure

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [day_id] => 1 [plan_id] => 3 [day_num] => 1 [schedule_time] => 1300866720 [checkin_time] => [fine] => ) 
    [1] => Array ( [day_id] => 2 [plan_id] => 3 [day_num] => 2 [schedule_time] => 1300953120 [checkin_time] => [fine] => ) 
    [2] => Array ( [day_id] => 3 [plan_id] => 3 [day_num] => 3 [schedule_time] => 1301039520 [checkin_time] => [fine] => ) 
    [3] => Array ( [day_id] => 4 [plan_id] => 3 [day_num] => 4 [schedule_time] => 1301125920 [checkin_time] => [fine] => ) )
```

What I want to be able to do is loop through it testing 'schedule_time' for specific times, if it matches the whole array is saved into a new array. So say array 0 and 1 matched it would be output like this

```
Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( [day_id] => 1 [plan_id] => 3 [day_num] => 1 [schedule_time] => 1300866720 [checkin_time] => [fine] => ) 
        [1] => Array ( [day_id] => 2 [plan_id] => 3 [day_num] => 2 [schedule_time] => 1300953120 [checkin_time] => [fine] => ))
```

Same structure etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically said everything already. You need to create a new [***array***](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and [*loop*](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) over the existing one and [*check some condition*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php).

```
$new_array = array();

foreach($array as $item) {
    if($item['schedule_time'] > something) {
        $new_array[] = $item;
    }
}
```

I recommend to read the documentation.

Comment: Many thanks for this. I have a hard time getting my head around foreach statements. Sitting down to learn this process off by heart.

Comment: @willmcneilly: Think about it like this: An array is a list of elements. The `foreach` loop gives you access to one these elements in each iteration. It is even close to English language: *For each of these elements do this.* The fact that the elements are arrays again does not make difference.

Comment: Just thought I'd add that it works perfectly but the second last bracket must be changed to a curly closing bracket. Small Syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

```
$mySpecialTimeToMatch = 0; //whatever time you want to match
$newArray = array();
foreach ($arrayScheduledTasks as $task) {
    foreach ($task as $key => $data) {
        if( "schedule_time" == $key && $mySpecialTimeToMatch == $data ) {
            $newArray[] = $task;
        }
    }
}

print_r($newArray);
```

Comment: Why so complicated? There is not need to loop over the inner array. It is an unnecessary overhead.

Comment: You are correct.  It is unnecessary overhead.  From a logical standpoint, it makes more sense.  Nested array matches a nested loop.  If speed is a concern, use Felix's solution.

Comment: @SeanC.: No, it does not make sense. One uses an array to have `O(1)` access time. If I know that I want to access the `5`th element, I do `$a[5]` and don't use a `for` loop until `i == 5`.

Comment: @willmcneilly: You don't need nested `foreach` loops at all. Honestly, the solution given is not good. Sorry.

Comment: Awesome, Felix!  Again, you've proven the same thing with which I agreed.  Your solution is faster.  The degree to which a solution makes sense is objective.  Something that makes sense to one person may not make sense to another.  Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Thanks anyway it's nice to see different methods of achieving the same thing